# Serve Webpage through webRTC

Tags: javascript, server, webrtc, turn

Is it possible to use the public ip and port that you get through the turn server to access a machine behind a router and firewall that I can't configure?

Use case would be a 'Internet of Things' - device, which needs to be accessed behind a arbitrary firewall/router. The device hosts a UI that has to be used. It shows all the data and gives options to configure the device.

I would prefer to host the UI myself and use the webRTC data channel to send the necessary data but it is not possible due to the preliminaries.

Usage of a VPN is also discouraged.

My first solution would be to use a browser engine to access a signaling server every 60 seconds or so to make the device accessible through the internet. When the client also connects to the signaling server the IoT-device sends the UI and all the data through the webRTC data channel, like a server would.

Comment: you should post what you tried so far

Comment: The client decided for a VPN solution. I have found a method online to [host websites in the browser via webRTC](http://www.peerjs.com/) but it did not satisfy my use case. The alternative, wich seems promising is to implement the hole punching myself or use a library to do it outside of the browser. More info about hole punching for peer to peer nat transversal can be found [here](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/). In the end VPN seems more 'tested and secure' and i feel more comfortable recommending using it.